# Error when installing ngx-captcha on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, recaptcha

I am trying to install `ngx-captcha` on one of my Angular projects and I am getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~8.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0" from ngx-captcha@9.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-captcha
npm ERR!   ngx-captcha@"9.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/shafkhan/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shafkhan/.npm/_logs/2021-03-11T10_15_02_731Z-debug.log
```

My Angular version and CLI versions are as follows:

```
Node: 12.16.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.29
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.29
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               8.3.29
@schematics/update                0.803.29
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems this version needs Angular 10. Try to install the previous stable version of ngx captcha as npm install ngx-captcha@5.0.4

Comment: Nope, it still gives me the same error :*(